# What is the optimal way of finding all the .mp3 files in a device?

Tags: python

The `os.walk(`) method is easy but it takes lot of time to scan through all the files?

Is there any method with less time and low processing power?

I've tried both the `os.walk()` and `glob()` methods but `glob` only returns files in the same directory and `os.walk` is too slow.

Comment: `os.walk` may be "too slow" ... but it is your only platform independent option.

Comment: Then you didn't use `**` with glob. Please provide some code of what you considered an optimal solution and people may be able to suggest improvements. However, StackOverflow isn't for asking for reviews of your code, nor for recommendations on libraries, frameworks, etc.

Comment: Unless you happen to know more about where the .mp3 files are, this is your only choice

Comment: On Linux (for example) there is an OS command called "locate" that allows you to find files by name.  However, it relies on a building a database of all  files in the file system, and updating it periodically.  (Files added between database updates won't show up.)

Answer (score 1):

you can try `scandir`

```
import os
import fnmatch

def find_mp3_files(root_dir):
    matches = []
    with os.scandir(root_dir) as entries:
        for entry in entries:
            if entry.is_file() and fnmatch.fnmatch(entry.name, '*.mp3'):
                matches.append(entry.path)
            elif entry.is_dir():
                matches.extend(find_mp3_files(entry.path))
    return matches

mp3_files = find_mp3_files('/path/to/root/directory')
```

Answer (score 1):

With `glob()` you can scan all system directories recursively.
Here is how you can do it:

```
import glob

# Use glob to find all the mp3 files in the specified root directory and its subdirectories
root_dir = '/path/to/root/directory/'
mp3_files = glob.glob(root_dir + '**/*.mp3', recursive=True)

print(mp3_files)
```

For linux based Operating systems including MacOS, you can use

```
root_dir = '/'
```

For Windows OS

```
root_dir = 'C:/' 
# Replace C with other drive letters present on your system.
```